# Calculate algorithm's complexity ( infinite algorithms )

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Considering this piece of Java code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class BreakWhileLoop {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Input an integer");
      n = input.nextInt();

      if (n == 0) {
        break;
      }
      System.out.println("You entered " + n);
    }
  } 
}
```

Let's take this particular case : `the user will always enter any integer except 0`.

1.Can i consider this code as an algorithm ?

2.If yes , how to calculate its complexity ?

Thanks

Comment: Well.. ask these questions: 1) What does this algorithm do? 2) What  data does this algorithm operate on?

Comment: Does it even make sense to talk about its complexity when it doesn't even terminate? There's nothing to scale with anything.

Comment: To calculate time complexity you have to know the input data. So if you know what numerical sequence, that ends with a zero, the user stuffs into this "algorithm", then it is linear. But to be honest, it doesn't make much sense to call this an algorithm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid trivial answers, let us relax the problem statement by removing the `except 0` condition.

Then yes, it is an algorithm, we can call it a `0 acceptor`.

Assuming that user input takes constant time, the time complexity is `O(N)` where `N` is the length of the nonzero sequence.

Comment: Obviously, if `N` is unbounded, so is the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

> "An algorithm is a finite sequence of well-defined instructions for
>   calculating a function (or executing a procedure) that terminates in a
>   well-defined ending state."

As taken from: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69083/what-is-an-algorithm

If the user will always keep inputting values then this is not an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It will run forever. Time complexity is used to specify an upper bound for the time an algorithms runs depending on the input. Since your code  will run forever  no matter what the input is, it is meaningless to talk about its time complexity.

Comment: But let's consider that we have a long algorithm including the above piece of code , is it logic to not talk about time complexity ?

Comment: As i said time complexity is used to specify an upper bound time limit based on the user input. It is meaningless to talk about time complexity of a code that is guaranteed to run forever.

Answer (score 0):

> Interaction is a more powerful paradigm than rule-based algorithms for computer problem solving, overturning the prevailing view that all computing is expressible as algorithms.

You can follow the details and proof of this in [this renowned article by Wegner](http://www.wit.at/events/wegner/cacm_may97_p80-wegner.pdf) which is "Why Interaction is More Powerful than Algorithm?"